# Display data in blade from multiple table in dtabase using Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display  fields from multiple table to single html table as per corresponding data in blade. But I am not getting any result

My Database Design :

```
District 
| id 
| district_name

Municipal
| id
| district_id
| Municipal_uid
| municipal_name 

Area
| id 
| area_name
| district_id
| municipal_id
```

This is what I am trying to achieve,

```
Area ID | Area Name | District Name | Municipal Name | municipal UID
```

My Model

> Area:

```
public function districts(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts');
}

public function municipals(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Municipals');
}
```

> Municipal:

```
public function district(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts');
}

public function approvedlayout(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Approvedlayouts');
}
```

> District:

```
 public function municipal(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Municipals');
}

public function approvedlayout(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Approvedlayouts');
}
```

blade

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead class="text-center">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Area ID</th>
                                    <th>Area Name</th>
                                    <th>District  Name </th>
                                    <th>Municipal Name</th>
                                    <th>Municipal UID</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody class="list">
                                @foreach ($areas as $layout)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$layout ->id}}</td>
                                    <td> {{ $layout-area_name }}</td>
                                    <td> {{ $layout->districts-> district_name }}</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{$areas-> links()}}
```

Controller

```
  public function index()
    {
        $areas = Area::simplePaginate(5);
        return view('admin.area.index',compact('areas'));
    }
```

When I try to display the district name

> ( {{ $layout->districts-> district_name }})

I am getting error,

> Trying to get property 'district_name' of non-object (View:
>   lapp/resources/views/area/index.blade.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your model so it knows about foreign key

```
Area:

public function districts(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
}

public function municipals(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Municipals','Municipal_uid','id');
}

Municipal:

public function district(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
}


District:

 public function municipal(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Municipals','id','district_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mubbashar, :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$layout->districts()->first()->district_name
```

Will show the first district.
If you have more than one, you can change first to get(). Then you'll need another foreach.

Comment: According to schema how can a layout (area) have multiple districts?

Comment: "public function districtS()"

Answer (score 0):

You could always just used the `leftJoin` an `select` function on your query builder to get those results. It'll also be much faster than calling it per row.

```
Area::select('areas.id','areas.name', 'districts.name as district_name', 'municipals.name as municipal_name', 'municipals.id as municipal_id')
    ->leftJoin('districts', 'districts.id', '=', 'area.district_id')
    ->leftJoin('municipals', 'municipals', '=', 'area.municipal_id')
    ->get();
```

Afterwards, you can refresh the stuff in the select function as `$layout->district_name`.